# Using MAX aggregate between two tables

Tags: sql, max, match, aggregate

I have two tables, employer and position:

**Employer**
eID
eName

**Position**
eID
salary

I need to match my eID between the two tables, determine what the max salary is, and print only the eName.  Any suggestions as to how I can do this?  I have tried multiple ways, but nothing seems to work.

I am not sure where to put in the max(salary) function:

```
select eName
from employer, position
where employer.eID = position.eID
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the name(s) of the people with the highest salary...

### Using a JOIN:

```
SELECT e.name
  FROM EMPLOYER e
  JOIN POSITION x ON x.eid = e.eid
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(salary) AS max_salary
          FROM POSITION) y ON y.max_salary = x.salary
```

### Using a subquery:

```
SELECT e.name
  FROM EMPLOYER e
  JOIN POSITION p ON p.eid = e.eid
 WHERE p.salary = (SELECT MAX(salary)
                     FROM POSITION)
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped so much!!  I am very new to SQL (just started learning it this week) and I forgot about renaming tables to create new ones.

Answer (score 1):

```
select e.ename,p.salary
from employer e ,position p
where p.salary=(select max(salary) from position)
and e.eid=p.eid
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables, sort, and get the first one:

```
select top 1 e.eName, p.salary
from Employer e
inner join Position p on p.eID = e.eID
order by p.salary desc
```

(This returns the salary also, but you can of course remove it if you really don't want it.)